# C++ double dispatch "extensible" without RTTI

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overloading, rtti, double-dispatch

Does anyone know a way to have double dispatch handled correctly in C++ *without* using RTTI and dynamic_cast<> and also a solution, in which the class hierarchy is extensible, that is the base class can be derived from further and its definition/implementation does not need to know about that? 
I suspect there is no way, but I'd be glad to be proven wrong :)

Comment: Is compile-time double dispatch an option for you? (I’m guessing probably not, but just in case it is, there is a simple solution.)

Comment: It's not, since it does not allow for extensibility (I'm trying to write a library, not just a predefined set of classes).

Comment: @Konrad, out of curiosity, are you thinking of CRTP? And if so, @George is there a reason why it's not viable?

Comment: Because I need dynamic polymorphism. Otherwise, it would have been perfectly viable.

Comment: @Nim No. Simply overloading (and [template subclassing](http://trac.mi.fu-berlin.de/seqan/wiki/Tutorial/TemplateSubclassing), which is used to generate a compile-time inheritance hierarchy, and which is similar to CRTP in some regards).

Comment: What is it that you want *not to use* from RTTI? Since we are talking about dynamic dispatch, *RTTI* **is** a requirement. If what you want is to minimize the number of manual `dynamic_cast`s (i.e. avoid having to have a `dynamic_cast` for each potential type of the argument at all levels, that might be feasible, but if you want to avoid `dynamic_cast` at all costs, then you need support from the language, and then the answer is simple: you cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that double (or higher order) dispatch doesn't scale.  With single
dispatch, and `n` types, you need `n` functions; for double dispatch `n^2`, and so on.  How you
handle this problem partially determines how you handle double dispatch.  One obvious solution is to
limit the number of derived types, by creating a closed hierarchy; in that case, double dispatch can
be implemented easily using a variant of the visitor pattern.  If you don't close the hierarchy,
then you have several possible approaches.

If you insist that every pair corresponds to a function, then you basically need a:

```
std::map<std::pair<std::type_index, std::type_index>, void (*)(Base const& lhs, Base const& rhs)>
                dispatchMap;
```

(Adjust the function signature as necessary.)  You also have to implement the `n^2` functions, and
insert them into the `dispatchMap`.  (I'm assuming here that you use free functions; there's no
logical reason to put them in one of the classes rather than the other.)  After that, you call:

```
(*dispatchMap[std::make_pair( std::type_index( typeid( obj1 ) ), std::type_index( typeid( obj2 ) )])( obj1, obj2 );
```

(You'll obviously want to wrap that into a function; it's not the sort of thing you want scattered
all over the code.)

A minor variant would be to say that only certain combinations are legal.  In this case, you can use
`find` on the `dispatchMap`, and generate an error if you don't find what you're looking for.
(Expect a lot of errors.)  The same solution could e used if you can define some sort of default
behavior.

If you want to do it 100% correctly, with some of the functions able to handle an intermediate class
and all of its derivatives, you then need some sort of more dynamic searching, and ordering to
control overload resolution.  Consider for example:

```
            Base
         /       \
        /         \
       I1          I2
      /  \        /  \
     /    \      /    \
    D1a   D1b   D2a   D2b
```

If you have an `f(I1, D2a)` and an `f(D1a, I2)`, which one should be chosen.  The simplest solution
is just a linear search, selecting the first which can be called (as determined by `dynamic_cast` on
pointers to the objects), and manually managing the order of insertion to define the overload
resolution you wish.  With `n^2` functions, this could become slow fairly quickly, however.  Since
there is an ordering, it should be possible to use `std::map`, but the ordering function is going to
be decidedly non-trivial to implement (and will still have to use `dynamic_cast` all over the
place).

All things considered, my suggestion would be to limit double dispatch to small, closed hierarchies,
and stick to some variant of the visitor pattern.

Comment: @James: since the OP mentioned *without RTTI*, I am afraid that `typeid` based solution are not suitable.

Comment: @Matthieu I thought he wanted to dispatch on the type.  In which case, without RTTI is a contradiction: you can't dispatch according to type at runtime without determining the type at runtime.

Comment: @James: there are other ways to "know" the type than RTTI. LLVM created a rather smart (and importantly opt-in) alternative for example.

Comment: Basically, I wanted RTTI off the table because of bad compiler support and that everybody says "You don't need RTTI in an embedded environment". However a variable indicating the type is a viable option. After all, a vtable essentially does that in a certain manner.

Comment: @Matthieu If you know the type at runtime, it is RTTI.  By definition.  You can use the RTTI provided by the C++ compiler, or you can implement your own; for specific cases (not needing complete genericity), what you implement may be much faster or smaller than what the compiler does, but it's still RTTI.

Comment: @James: It seems we use the same word for different purposes. For me RTTI specifically relate to the C++ Standard implementation of RunTime Type Information (used for `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`). Note that in the LLVM example I presented, the use of `isa<>` and `cast<>` is supported differently by a weaker form of RTTI. Instead of having full runtime information, you only know if the cast is possible.

Comment: @Matthieu Yes.  I'm using the term in its everyday sense. As far as I know, it doesn't have any specialized C++ sense.  (I can't find the term anywhere in the standard.)  Anything which provides information about the type at runtime is RTTI.  (I was using the term before C++ had support for it, to describe what we'd implemented, for example.)

Comment: You can easily modify this answer to work without RTTI by using `typeid(type)` (as opposed to `typeid(expression)`) and wrapping it in a virtual function. RTTI meaning specifically what's in the C++ language (`typeid(expression)` and `dynamic_cast`) that can e.g. be disabled with `-fno-rtti`.

Answer (score 6):

The ["visitor pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) in C++ is often equated with double dispatch.  It uses no RTTI or dynamic_casts.

See also the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429849/double-dispatch-multimethods-in-c).

Comment: OK, but then the Visitor must know the whole class hierarchy, which, too, is unacceptable. Is ther no other way?

Comment: Plus, the Visitor pattern must visit only leafs in the class hierarchy.

Comment: @George Penn: it can visit other things that leaves.

Comment: @Matthieu Yep, I just checked that. My mistake.

Comment: @Matthieu Actually, I think it would be a problem for a Visitor to visit both a parent and a child classes, since that would be the nasty type of overloading that inheritance does not tolerate, and the abstract Visitor must be derived from. If I'm incorrect, would you elaborate?

Comment: @George Penn: You are right that by default, the Visitor will go to the most derived class that overloaded the `accept` method (and for which the visitor has a `visit` overload). You can perfectly implement `Child::accept(v)` as `{ v.visit(*this); Parent::visit(*this); }` though.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is trivial. `dynamic_cast` involves two things: run-time check and a type cast. The former requires RTTI, the latter does not. All you need to do to replace dynamic_cast with a functionality that does the same without requiring RTTI is to have your own method to check the type at run-time. To do this, all you need is a simple virtual function that returns some sort of identification of what type it is or what more-specific interface it complies to (that can be an enum, an integer ID, even a string). For the cast, you can safely do a `static_cast` once you have already done the run-time check yourself and you are sure that the type you are casting to is in the object's hierarchy. So, that solves the problem of emulating the "full" functionality of `dynamic_cast` without needing the built-in RTTI. Another, more involved solution is to create your own RTTI system (like it is done in several softwares, like LLVM that Matthieu mentioned).

The second problem is a big one. How to create a double dispatch mechanism that scales well with an extensible class hierarchy. That's hard. At compile-time (static polymorphism), this can be done quite nicely with function overloads (and/or template specializations). At run-time, this is much harder. As far as I know, the only solution, as mentioned by Konrad, is to keep a dispatch table of function pointers (or something of that nature). With some use of static polymorphism and splitting dispatch functions into categories (like function signatures and stuff), you can avoid having to violate type safety, in my opinion. But, before implementing this, you should think very hard about your design to see if this double dispatch is really necessary, if it really needs to be a run-time dispatch, and if it really needs to have a separate function for each combination of two classes involved (maybe you can come up with a reduced and fixed number of abstract classes that capture all the truly distinct methods you need to implement).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check how LLVM implement `isa<>`, `dyn_cast<>` and `cast<>` as a template system, since it's compiled without RTTI.

It is a bit cumbersome (requires tidbits of code in every class involved) but very lightweight.

[LLVM Programmer's Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa) has a nice example and a reference to the implementation.

(All 3 methods share the same tidbit of code)

Answer (score 2):

You can fake the behaviour by implementing the compile-time logic of multiple dispatch yourself. However, this is *extremely* tedious. [Bjarne Stroustrup has co-authored a paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2216.pdf) describing how this could be implemented *in a compiler*.

The underlying mechanism – a dispatch table – could be dynamically generated. However, using this approach you would of course lose all syntactical support. You’d need to to maintain 2-dimensional matrix of method pointers and manually look up the correct method depending on the argument types. This would render a simple (hypothetical) call

```
collision(foo, bar);
```

*at least* as complicated as

```
DynamicDispatchTable::lookup(collision_signature, FooClass, BarClass)(foo, bar);
```

since you didn’t want to use RTTI. And this is assuming that all your methods take only two arguments. As soon as more arguments are required (even if those aren’t part of the multiple dispatch) this becomes more complicated still, and would require circumventing type safety.

Comment: Thanks, this is an answer, however James' answer is quite more detailed, so I'm accepting his.